# understanding of properties assignment

Tags: objective-c, properties

i'm working with a sprite kit through their "Adventure" example, and have a question about properties...
For example we have a model

```
APAplayer.h
@interface APAPlayer : NSObject
   @property (nonatomic) APAHeroCharacter *hero;
   a lot of properties...
@end
```

and scene

```
Scene.m
@interface APAMultiplayerLayeredCharacterScene ()
    @property (nonatomic) APAPlayer *defaultPlayer;
@end
```

And we have a code like:

```
APAplayer *defaultPlayer = self.defaultPlayer;
APAHeroCharacter *hero = nil;
if ([self.heroes count] > 0) {
    hero = defaultPlayer.hero;
}

if (defaultPlayer.moveRequested) {...}
```

And i have question:
Why did they create new instance of VZPlayer and then assigning property to this instance ? What is changes if write this so:

```
APAHeroCharacter *hero = nil;
if ([self.heroes count] > 0) {
    hero = self.defaultPlayer.hero;
}

if (self.defaultPlayer.moveRequested) {...}
```

Sorry if it's very newbie question, i'm really don't understand is it only because 5 symbols..is it saver or something else ? The MAIN question is why did they using local var and not self

**EDITED**

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    APAPlayer *defaultPlayer = self.defaultPlayer;
    UITouch *touch = defaultPlayer.movementTouch;
    if ([touches containsObject:touch]) {
        defaultPlayer.targetLocation = [touch locationInNode:defaultPlayer.hero.parent];
        if (!defaultPlayer.fireAction) {
            defaultPlayer.moveRequested = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Why not...

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = defaultPlayer.movementTouch;
        if ([touches containsObject:touch]) {
            self.defaultPlayer.targetLocation = [touch locationInNode:defaultPlayer.hero.parent];
            if (!self.defaultPlayer.fireAction) {
                self.defaultPlayer.moveRequested = YES;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original code snippet, the `VZPlayer *defaultPlayer` in the code is new and actually completely separate from the original `APAPlayer *defaultPlayer`. The `VZPlayer` is local to the code snippet, whereas the `APAPlayer` is part of the object and changes to it can be seen by other bits of code.

When you call `self.defaultPlayer`, you're using the one that's in the property. Using the one without `self` is the local version.

Edit:

In this case, it's possible for `self.defaultPlayer` to change if you have multithreaded code. Doing it this way makes sure the rest of the code still acts on the same `defaultPlayer` and doesn't do some things to the original `defaultPlayer` and the rest to a new one. These kinds of errors can result in inconsistent and unexpected. states.

Comment: sorry, i am edited. I'm interesting why did they using local var and in if else also not using self.defaultPlayer

Comment: Added edit to my answer. In short, it's probably to guard against `self.defaultPlayer` property pointing to a new player object due to another thread. Saving the pointer as done in the code example ensures that you're at least still using the same player.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see is that the new instance variable they create, `defaultPlayer` is an instance of `VZPlayer` while `defaultPlayer` (the instance variable of APAMultiplayerLayeredCharacterScene) is an instance of `APAPlayer`.

It looks like it might be an attempt to cast but if that was the case, I'd expect it to look like this:

```
VZPlayer *defaultPlayer = (VZPlayer *)self.defaultPlayer
```